# Do tasks really work concurrently on single core processor with multithreadding?

Tags: multiprocessing, multitasking

I understand that tasks can be runned concurrently in multicore systems. Each tasks are seperated different core.

But in single core systems? Is it just task switching?

Answer (score 0):

In most systems concurrency is simulated. The OS switches from task to task, allocating the resources.

In single core systems, this is the only way to run multiple threads at the same time. And even in multicore systems you would have something similar in place. In modern systems you simply have more tasks running than the number of cores you have. So often the OS would be shuffling through threads based on some factors, allocating them to the available cores.